# Parsing date/time strings problem

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I'm having some problems finding an algorithm which successfully parses a wide range of date/time strings. I need something which not only handles the common formats such as *yyyy-MM-dd* etc, but also something a little more exotic such as the Swedish long date format which is *'den 'd MMMM yyyy* which allows something like "den 1 december 2010". It only needs to handle formats which Windows has been set to, i.e. if you set it to Swedish then I wouldn't expect it to handle French etc.

I was hoping that the MFC COleDateTime's ParseDateTime would handle it, but it doesn't appear to.

**Does anyone know of anything which is versatile enough to handle these various date formats?**

Answer (score 1):

[Boost.DateTime](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/date_time.html) has a flexible range of parsing options.  See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.io_tutorial) for an initial example.  You can specify your own input/output format using the flags [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.format_flags).

You could use this to build a factory class that generates a parser/streamer based on the locale of your system.